# Orders Products and Order_Line Hibernate Relationship with Composite Keys

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Ok so today I have spent all day trying to figure out how to map a relationship between Orders, Products, and OrderLine with hibernate using annotations all java config.

I want OrderLine to be a junction table with extra fields, that joins Products and Orders.

Orders has a OneToMany relationsbhip with OrderLine - One order has many order lines.

Each Order has one or more OrderLines, Each OrderLine has one Order, Each OrderLine has one Product, Each Product can have 0 or more OrderLines.

From what I have been following along with tutorials, there are two ways to do it.  One being with @Embeddable, @EmbeddedId annotations and the other being @IdClass annotations, I have tried both with no success I will post my code for my shot at @IdClass method.

My orders class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "order")
    private Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<>();
     ...some extra properties relevant to all orders
    public Order(){}

    ...setters/getters
}
```

My Products class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product implements Serializable  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name = "product_id")
public Integer product_id; // primary key
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "product")
private Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<>();
 ...other properties
public Product() {
}
...setters/getters
}
```

Here is my OrderLine Class

```
@Entity
@IdClass(OrderLineId.class)
@Table(name="order_line")
public class OrderLine implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id 
@Column(name = "product_id", insertable= false, updatable= false)   
public Integer product_id;

@Id 
@Column(name = "order_id", insertable= false, updatable= false)
public Integer order_id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Product product;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Order order;

@Column(name = "product_quantity", unique = false, nullable = false)
private int productQuantity;
...additional fields associated with each OrderLine
```

And finally my OrderLineId implementation

```
public class OrderLineId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer order_id;
private Integer product_id;

public OrderLineId(){}

public OrderLineId(Integer order_id, Integer product_id) {
    this.order_id = order_id;
    this.product_id = product_id;
}

@Column(name = "order_id")
public Integer getOrder() {
    return this.order_id;
}

public void setOrder(Integer order_id) {
    this.order_id = order_id;
}

@Column(name = "product_id")
public Integer getProduct() {
    return this.product_id;
}

public void setProduct(Integer product_id) {
    this.product_id = product_id;
}

  @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return order_id + product_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof OrderLineId){
            OrderLineId orderLineId = (OrderLineId) obj;
            return orderLineId.order_id == order_id && orderLineId.product_id == product_id;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the exception I am getting

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'orderlines0_.order' in 'field list'
```

when I visit the end point below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testorder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView testOrder(){

    Order order = orderService.findOrderById(23);
    Product product = productService.findProduct(2);

    OrderLine ol = new OrderLine(product, order);

    ol.setSize("large");
    ol.setProductQuantity(30);

    orderService.saveOrderLine(ol);
    return null;
}
```

Please can somebody help me, this is driving me crazy....

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out - I ended up using embeddable method instead based on this guys excellent tutorial h[ere](http://hedleyproctor.com/2014/02/hibernate-example-4-many-to-many-associations/.)

He goes through 3 major ways to implement many to many assosiations - a simple junction only table, a junction table (with additional fields) which is the method I needed to implement, and finally a less popular method where the class is mapped as a component.

Answer (score 0):

After going through your question and code, I think you have got your design wrong.

You say

> want OrderLine to be a junction table with extra fields, that joins Products and Orders.

However you have only two variables, Order and Product in your OrderLine Class.

If I am not wrong, What you really need is a **many-to-many** table.

Your table `order_line` would contain two columns `order_id` and `product_id`, having foreign key to table `orders` and `products` respectively.

Your Order class would be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    //id of table Order

    @ManyToMany(
      targetEntity = Product.class,
cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "order_line",
joinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false, updatable = false),
inverseJoinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false, updatable = false))
public Set<Product> products= new HashSet(0);


             ...some extra properties relevant to all orders
    public Order(){}

    ...setters/getters
}
```

Your Product Class would look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product implements Serializable  {

@Id
@Column(name = "product_id")
public Integer product_id; // primary key

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "products", targetEntity = Order.class) private Set<Order> order = new HashSet<>();

 ...other properties
public Product() {
}
...setters/getters
}
```

As you can see, from Order entity you can get 'products' and from Product entity you can get 'orders'. This should server your purpose. No need to use 'OrderLine' class.

Other major errors in code:
 - @Id is used to represent Primary key. You have used @Id multiple times for single class.
 - In 'Order' class @Id given to Set, and @Id is used along with @OneToMany, which won't work.

Code provided would help you if, indeed what you need is many-to-many table.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment.  Well that is how I originally had my code, but I need to have extra fields in the function table so a simple ManyToMany association would not work - OrderLine is going to have about 6 properties associated with it, 'product_size', 'product_color', etc. Does that make sense now?  Also the multiple use of @Id was purposely done, the tutorial I was following said to do that when constructing a composite key derived from other entities primary keys. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work on my last try last night by doing this change

in OrderLine I removed the product_id and order_id fields and placed the @Id annotation over both ManyToOne relationships like so

```
@Entity
@IdClass(OrderLineId.class)
@Table(name="order_line")
public class OrderLine implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Product product;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Order order;

@Column(name = "product_quantity", unique = false, nullable = false)
private int productQuantity;
...additional fields associated with each OrderLine
```

I did not think this woudl work but correct table with correct values was updated, is this valid?

Thank you